# How To Detect Whether strategy.exit() is Triggered?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

How can I detect if strategy.exit() has been triggered or not?

The code below works fine for trades that exist on a different candle other than the entry candle:

```
detect_exit  = (strategy.position_size[1] > 0 and strategy.position_size == 0) or (strategy.position_size[1] < 0 and strategy.position_size == 0)
```

The line of code above doesn't catch exists that occur on the same entry candle.

**Do you have any idea how to catch exits that happened on the same candle of the entry candle?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference trade prices and times using the closed trades built ins. Here we check position size and the current bar relative to the exit bar

```
detect_exit = strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1) == bar_index
```

Cheers and have a great day

Comment: I got this error Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 1026: Could not find function or function reference 'strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index'..... Are you using v5?

Comment: Yea that is version 5. It's the newest, but has been out for over 6 months. There were lots of very useful functions like the one above released with v5. Best to convert and use the newest especially if you are going to continue to learn Pine.